# Could not save file in the docker image after "docker commit"

Tags: docker, commit

I use the command:

```
docker run -it -v /myhostpath:/dockerpath $container
```

so I get a mapping from a host dir to a docker dir, and I do see the files shared by both dirs.

After that, I exit the container, commit and save the image.
However, when I open the container again, the shared files are gone.

Could anyone tell me what is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-v` option is like using the `mount` command to mount an external file system.   Directories mapped into a container with `-v` are not in the container's filesystem.  Therefore committing the changes in the container's filesystem to a new image does not include these external files.

If you want to copy some external files to the container, you would need to use `-v` to temporarily mount the directory and then use a `cp` command to copy to a directory local to the container, and then commit.

Or, you could include the files using `ADD` or `COPY` in your `Dockerfile`

If the external files can be thought of as essential input or output for the container, that is separate from the container and could be needed elsewhere (log files, calculation results, database data, etc), or are supposed to be kept secret, then you should not copy them to the container.  Instead, continue using `-v` to mount that directory on the container.

Comment: Thanks! I find that only when I cp the files to /usr/local then the files could be saved after I exit. Even though I cp the files to /root it won't work. Why is that??

Comment: @James `/` is the *root directory*. I don't know what `/root` is (*root-slash-root*). I'm guessing that's a mount point for the host's root drive.

Comment: `/root` is typically the root user's home directory.